# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Compiler message:
lib/range_slider.dart:2:8: Error: Can't access platform private library.
import 'dart:_http';
       ^
Compiler failed on /Users/user/FlutterApp/cliniva_doctor_app/lib/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/user/Library/FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 782
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm64'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/user/Library/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1